# LNK2019/2001 error when compiling a Boost project built from CMake the first time, but not the second

Tags: visual-c++, boost, cmake, linker-errors

I have a project that uses Boost, with CMake for the build system. The first time that I try to compile the ALL_BUILD after CMake generation, it fails while linking with a LNK2019 error and 2 LNK2001 errors - but if I make any modification to the CMakeLists.txt (even just adding a space) and compile again, it works just fine.

Here's my CMakeLists.txt **(Updated)**:

```
 project(OurProject)

 set(CMAKE_MFC_FLAG 2)

 file(GLOB_RECURSE sources
     *.c
     *.cpp
     *.cc)

 file(GLOB_RECURSE headers
     *.h
     *.hpp
     *.inl)

 file(GLOB_RECURSE resources
     *.rc)

 file(GLOB_RECURSE definitions
     *.def)

 set_source_files_properties(${resources} PROPERTIES LANGUAGE RC)

 add_library(OurProject SHARED ${sources} ${headers} ${resources} ${definitions})

 target_compile_options(OurProject
     PRIVATE
         -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
         -DNO_WARN_MBCS_MFC_DEPRECATION
 )

 find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS filesystem thread regex)

 add_subdirectory(../ourLib ourLib)

 target_link_libraries(OurProject
     PRIVATE
         ourLib
         Boost::regex
         Boost::filesystem
         Boost::thread
 )
```

And these are the three errors it comes up with:

```
 LNK2019    unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl boost::throw_exception(class std::exception const &)" (?throw_exception@boost@@YAXAEBVexception@std@@@Z) referenced in function "public: __cdecl boost::detail::shared_count::shared_count<class boost::io::basic_altstringbuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > *,class boost::io::basic_oaltstringstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::No_Op>(class boost::io::basic_altstringbuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > *,class boost::io::basic_oaltstringstream<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::No_Op)" (??$?0PEAV?$basic_altstringbuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@io@boost@@VNo_Op@?$basic_oaltstringstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@12@@shared_count@detail@boost@@QEAA@PEAV?$basic_altstringbuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@io@2@VNo_Op@?$basic_oaltstringstream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@42@@Z)
 LNK2001    unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl boost::throw_exception(class std::exception const &)" (?throw_exception@boost@@YAXAEBVexception@std@@@Z)
 LNK2001    unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl boost::throw_exception(class std::exception const &)" (?throw_exception@boost@@YAXAEBVexception@std@@@Z)
```

**Update 2**: The CMakeLists of ourLib.
     include_guard(GLOBAL)

```
 project(ourLib)

 set(CMAKE_MFC_FLAG 2)

 add_library(ourLib
     src/ourLibSource.cpp
     include/ourLibHeader.h
 )

 target_include_directories(ourLib
     PUBLIC
         $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
         $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
     PRIVATE
         ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src
 )

 target_compile_options(ourLib
     PUBLIC
         -D_AFXDLL
         -D_AFXEXT
     PRIVATE
         -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
         -DNO_WARN_MBCS_MFC_DEPRECATION
 )
```

Comment: I really recommend that you use the imported targets (like `Boost::filesystem`) as those will also include all dependencies, which isn't specified for `Boost_LIBRARIES`. See the [Find Boost documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html) for details.

Comment: Ah I like being specific with my links, so that's a good tip. Didn't fix the problem though - swapping in boost::filesystem, thread, and regex for Boost_LIBRARIES (see updated code) still led to a link error on the first compile after CMake generation.

Comment: What is under `../ourLib` directory which you are adding to you project? Differences between the first and the second run could be result of wrong dependencies. E.g., if `ourLib` uses Boost, but are not linked with it. BTW, you have two libraries - which library causes these linking errors?

Comment: @Tsyvarev Errors happen during linking of the OurProject build, but ourLib and everything else seems to do its stuff fine (we have another project that links to this library as well but doesn't use Boost like this one does, and it also links fine). I'll update with the CMakeLists for that library.